# High Throughput Using MQ Series from .NET

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I'm having some obscure performance issues when using MQ Series from a .NET WCF service.

The service is multi-threaded - it receives many requests per second and puts it on the queue. Since connecting to the queue is considered costly, I decided that the service is a singleton, which connects once to the queue (as soon as it's instantiated) and then accepts many parallel calls to put messages on the queue.

On my current environment, I can handle up to 850 calls per second. After this number, something starts to go very wrong. All of a sudden I start getting **timeout** errors from WCF. All my analysis points to the fact that the PUT command is taking too long and my guess is that it is syncronizing the threads; This would mean that the more requests I have, the longer each one takes.

Some samples from my code:

```
// The objects below are members of the singleton service
_mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_config.QueueManagerName,
                            channelConfig[0], channelConfig[2]);

_mqQueueEscrita = _mqQueueManager.AccessQueue(_config.QueueConnectionName,
                            MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT);
```

And them comes the writing method:

```
    public void EscreverMensagemObject(object entrada_)
    {
        try
        {

            var mensagemMq = new MQMessage { Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING, Expiry = MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED };
            mensagemMq.WriteObject(entrada_);
            var opcoesMqPut = new MQPutMessageOptions();

            _mqQueueEscrita.Put(mensagemMq, opcoesMqPut);
        }
        catch (MQException mqEx)
        {
            if (mqEx.ReasonCode == MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN)
                Reconectar();
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format(ERRO_AO_ESCREVER_MENSAGEM, mqEx.Reason, mqEx.Message), mqEx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(ERRO_AO_ESCREVER_MENSAGEM, ex.HResult, ex.Message), ex);
        }

    }
```

That's the essence of it. Am I doing something wrong or forgetting to set some options that would help me achieve a higher performance?

Comment: Can you show the connection options (MQC.CNO_xxx) you are using for creating a connection?

Comment: @Shashi, I think I'm not actually using any. Should I?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you might be getting into a race condition when multiple threads are trying to use the same connection to put messages. I suggest you to try `MQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK` option when creating connection to queue manager. This option indicates that connection and object handles allocated by one thread of a process can be used by other threads belonging to the same process. However, only one thread at a time can use any particular handle; that is, only serial use of a handle is permitted. If a thread tries to use a handle that is already in use by another thread, the call blocks (waits) until the handle becomes available.

More details on different MQCNO_ are [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q095480_.htm)